# Need a cron expression

Tags: cron, cron-task

I am trying to get a cron expression through cron convertors online but it won't be able to do the same.
Some please help. I need a cron expression which should run every 3 hours starting at 00:10.

```
00:10
03:10
06:10
...
```

Also I need a cron expression that runs every 30 mins starting from 00:00.

```
00:00
00:30
01:00
...
```

something like this^

I tried

- 10/3 * * * *
  and
  */30 * * * *

Answer (score 0):

> I need a cron expression which should run every 3 hours starting at
> 00:10

Simply with

```
10 0/3 * * * your_command
```

This way, the cron will run the specified command at 10 minutes past midnight (10 0) and then every 3 hours thereafter (0/3)

> Also I need a cron expression that runs every 30 mins starting from
> 00:00

Then this might do the work

```
0,30 0-23/1 * * * /path/to/command
```

So it will run at 00:00 and 00:30 every day (0,30), every hour (0-23/1), and regardless of the day of the month, month, or day of the week (*)